# how to print recursively a Python dictionary and its subdictionaries with whitespace alignment into columns

Tags: dictionary, printing, tabs, alignment, whitespace

I want to create a function that can take a dictionary of dictionaries such as the following

```
information = {
    "sample information": {
        "ID": 169888,
        "name": "ttH",
        "number of events": 124883,
        "cross section": 0.055519,
        "k factor": 1.0201,
        "generator": "pythia8",
        "variables": {
            "trk_n": 147,
            "zappo_n": 9001
        }
    }
}
```

and then print it in a neat way such as the following, with alignment of keys and values using whitespace:

```
sample information:
   ID:                 169888
   name:               ttH
   number of events:   124883
   cross section:      0.055519
   k factor:           1.0201
   generator:          pythia8
   variables:
      trk_n:           147
      zappo_n:         9001
```

My attempt at the function is the following:

```
def printDictionary(
    dictionary = None,
    indentation = ''
    ):
    for key, value in dictionary.iteritems():
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            print("{indentation}{key}:".format(
            indentation = indentation,
            key = key
        ))
            printDictionary(
                dictionary = value,
                indentation = indentation + '   '
            )
        else:
            print(indentation + "{key}: {value}".format(
                key = key,
                value = value
            ))
```

It produces the output like the following:

```
sample information:
   name: ttH
   generator: pythia8
   cross section: 0.055519
   variables:
      zappo_n: 9001
      trk_n: 147
   number of events: 124883
   k factor: 1.0201
   ID: 169888
```

As is shown, it successfully prints the dictionary of dictionaries recursively, however is does not align the values into a neat column. What would be some reasonable way of doing this for dictionaries of arbitrary depth?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [pprint](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pprint.html) module. Instead of writing your own function, you can do this:

```
import pprint
pprint.pprint(my_dict)
```

Be aware that this will print characters such as `{` and `}` around your dictionary and `[]` around your lists, but if you can ignore them, `pprint()` will take care of all the nesting and indentation for you.